# Does my hidden files (in android phone) get deleted if there is no enough space to restore them?

Tags: storage, hidden

I tried to restore my hidden files on my android phone. I had less than 20% available space while the hidden files size was more than 30%. It gave me a warning of out of space memory. A box appeared where I quickly clicked the cancel button with reflex without reading what was written. I thought that my files were still there in the hidden folder but they were not. They were deleted completely. My free space also increased by that much. Does it happen like this?

Comment: No. This doesn't happen normally. How exactly did you hide the files?

Comment: Please describe in details what you mean by "hidden files". Are you talking about files in a "dot directory" (directories that starts with a dot)?  Or are you talking about files that have been hidden by a specific app?

Comment: Additionally this question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1595448/does-my-encrypted-hidden-files-in-android-phone-get-deleted-if-there-is-no-eno where already had been noted that your question is missing important details but you again posted it (using a different account).